# Combining [postgres] and [postgresql] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tags [postgres](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres) and [postgresql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) are exactly the same. Would it be possible to combine these?

Comment: One can be made a synonym of the other. As `postgres` is a nickname, `postgresql` should be the master. There is a tag synonym suggestion here that can be voted on: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql/synonyms

Comment: This synonym was suggested three weeks ago and was merely awaiting moderator approval, which has been done.  Tag synonyms may be suggested through the link at the bottom of the main site's [tags page](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll know where to go to for future tag suggestions and comments. Cheers!

Comment: This problem can no longer be reproduced. Changes have rendered the question obsolete